# Extracting list of functions into a standalone function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a pipe of functions `fun1 $ fun2 $ fun3` applied to a variable `var` as `fun1 $ fun2 $ fun3 var`. How could I extract this pipe `fun1 $ fun2 $ fun3` into standalone function `fun = (fun1 $ fun2 $ fun3)` that can be appllied to a `var` as `fun var`?

For example, I have a following pipe of functions: `BS.unpack $ JSON.encode var`. I want to extract `BS.unpack $ JSON.encode` from the statement `BS.unpack $ JSON.encode var` into `let fun = BS.unpack . JSON.encode`, but I get an error:

```
No instance for (JSON.ToJSON a0)
  arising from a use of `JSON.encode'
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
```

What is wrong with my function extraction?

Comment: How/where do these functions get applied to the variable?

Comment: Regarding your edit, can you give us the code in more context?

Answer (score 6):

What you're looking for is the function composition operator, `.`. This works as follows:

```
(f . g) x = f (g x) = f $ g x
```

Therefore, `fun = fun1 . fun2 . fun3` is what you're looking for.